# selected items don't have to appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

I was taught and heard that in sql/mysql, items in `select` clause **must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function** as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)

However, the example below may have changed my mind.

Two tables:
**Student (sid is the key)**

```
sid  | name | email
========================
99901| mike | mike@a.edu
99902| jane | jane@b.edu
99903| peter| pete@b.edu
```

**Took (sid+oid together is the key, oid stands for offering id)**

```
sid  | oid| grade
==================
99901| 1  | 100
99901| 2  | 30
99901| 3  | 40
99902| 4  | 100
99902| 5  | 100
99902| 6  | 40
99903| 6  | 95
```

**Question**: I want to find the sid, name and average grade of each student who has taken at least 2 courses.

**Answer**:

```
select s.sid, name, avg(grade) as average
from Student as s, Took as t
where s.sid = t.sid
group by s.sid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

**Result:**

```
sid  | name | avgerage
=======================
99901| mike | 56.6667
99902| jane | 80.0000
```

Based on **must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**, the query should have been incorrect because `name` is neither in group clause nor an aggregate function.

I looked some posts and [this](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate/), my understanding is that although `name` is neither in group clause nor an aggregate function, we group by `sid` which is the key and each `sid` only correspond to one `name`, so it won't return multiple options from which sql doesn't know which one to return. To confirm my understanding, if I select one more column `email`, it's still ok; but if I select `oid`, it gives error because each `sid` corresponds to more than one `oid`.

Could someone correct my understanding if it is wrong or elaborate more on this statement: `must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Thanks.

**First Edit**:

Btw, I tested in MySQL 8.0.17

**Second Edit**:

Just a summary of useful links when you read the answers/comments below.

[Functional depedency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

[SQL standard change](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: `mysql` will make inferences for you when it comes to this, while all other major dbms will rigidly enforce the rule.  I'd recommend simply following the rule even in `mysql` to save yourself any confusion, but you seem to have a perfect understanding of it.

Comment: @AaronDietz Don't know about other vendors, but in MySQL there can be performance issues when non-indexed columns are included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: See: [Detection of Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Comment: The [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) controls this, btw. (It's on by default in mysql 8...) [More reading](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: This blogpost (old but still relevant till today) can clear all misconceptions and myths surrounding `FULL_GROUP_BY` and SQL standard: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: All non-aggregated columns must be in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: *"All non-aggregated columns must be in GROUP BY"* Yes before ANSI SQL standard 1999 @Eric after ANSI SQL standard 1999  has Functional Dependency (which also exists for 20 years now) which allows non-aggregated columns to be used in the SELECT it is really a thing something which MySQL and PostgreSQL supports..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were taught right.

According to the SQL Standard when you use `GROUP BY` the columns that can appear in the `SELECT` clause fall into three categories:

1. Columns included in the `GROUP BY` clause. In this case you have `s.sid`.
2. Aggregated columns. In this case you have `avg(grade)`.
3. Functionally dependent columns of case #1. Since `s.sid` is the PK of the table, you can include `s.name` without aggregating it.

So all good.

However, you should know that MySQL 5.7.4 and older do allow you to include other columns in non-aggregated form. This is a bug/feature of MySQL that I personally find error prone. If you do this, MySQL will **silently** pick one value *randomly* without aggregating it and without telling you.

This functionality can be turned on by using the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` configuration parameter (as @Shawn pointed out in the comments) in newer versions of MySQL, to allow old/bad queries to run. I would try to avoid using it, though.

Comment: MySQL 5.7.5+ with running sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY does correctly implement ANSI/ISO SQL 1999 standard regrading of detection of functional dependence rules as far i know...

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
select s.sid, s.name, avg(grade) as average
from Student s join
     Took t
     on s.sid = t.sid
group by s.sid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This will work because of something called *functional dependencies*.  Basically, this is the part of the standard that says:  *If you `group by` a primary key or unique key, then you can include any of the columns from that table.*

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) is documentation on the subject.

That is, because the database *knows* that `s.sid` is unique, it is safe to use other columns.  This is part of the standard.  The only other common database that I am aware of that supports this is Postgres.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. One thing I don't understand is why the explicit `JOIN` is better than just `cartisian product`, in this example, they perform the same functionality, maybe because of the speed issue?

Comment: Readablity as it is directly clear this is inner joining, in the MySQL optimisation those explicit JOIN would become comma join again @Kenny As comma join only supports CROSS JOIN/INNER JOIN result, where explicit JOIN in MySQL supports CROSS/LEFT/RIGHT/INNER so the query can be changed more simply if you need other results ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. I also just found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138355/whats-the-difference-between-comma-separated-joins-and-join-on-syntax-in-mysql)