# How mySQL Update multiple tables query work?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I would like to know the working of **MySQL** `UPDATE table1 [,tables] SET col1=val1[,cols]` query.
Also, how is it different from `UPDATE tables with JOIN` query?

Comment: Is this a question about comma joins vs explicit joins? If so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138355/whats-the-difference-between-comma-separated-joins-and-join-on-syntax-in-mysql#:~:text=The%20comma%20operator%20is%20equivalent,clause%20into%20an%20ON%20clause.

Comment: I read the document but was not able to understand how it is working.
' UPDATE t1,t2 SET t1.colName1=5, SET t2.colName1=3 ' 
How t1 and t2 is joined in the above query ?

Comment: Tables t1 and t2 are comma joined (long unfashionable but still working) you should expand your reading to include comma joins see the link I posted and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html. BTW a comma join without a where condition is the same as a cross join.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you for your explanation . I still have one more doubt.
In Update query with comma separated join , the WHERE condition shall be true for same row multiple time. Will the same row be updated multiple times ?

Comment: For example?...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE T1, T2,
[INNER JOIN | LEFT JOIN] T1 ON T1.C1 = T2. C1
SET T1.C2 = T2.C2, 
    T2.C3 = expr
WHERE condition
```

Comment: Although , let's face it, LEFT JOIN is vanishingly unlikely in this contest

Comment: Do you mean , there is implicit inner join in UPDATE multi_tables query ?