# How to full join the two tables with the null values as well?

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join, sql-null

I'm using `MySQL 5.5 Command Line Client`.

What I want:

[image: is this]

What I tried last:

`SELECT e.event_id,e.title,e.description,e.event_date,e.image, sum(d.amount) as total,count(d.event_id) as total_donors FROM event e,donation d where d.event_id = e.event_id group by e.event_id;`

This joins the table but I want the null value as well, How can I modify this to get the last row in the desired results table(in the image attached)?

Also, what is this type of join called?

Thanks.

Comment: 'what is this type of join called?' - outdated or a comma join. please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html for how mysql treats them and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138355/whats-the-difference-between-comma-separated-joins-and-join-on-syntax-in-mysql

Comment: just do `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: The command line client version isn't relevant.  Check the server version with `select version();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query just need to convert using `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT e.event_id,e.title,e.description,e.event_date,e.image, 
       /*1*/
       sum(ifnull(d.amount,0)) as total,
       count(d.event_id) as total_donors 
FROM event e 
/*2*/
LEFT JOIN donation d 
/*3*/
ON d.event_id = e.event_id 
group by e.event_id;
```

Observe the following markings in the query above:

`/*1*/` add `ifnull` in the sum operation to return 0 instead of null. This will also prevent null result if one of the value in sum is null.

`/*2*/` change comma join to `LEFT JOIN` particularly because you want all rows from the left table are shown despite having no match in the table on the right.

`/*3*/` change `where` to `ON`.

Here is a fiddle demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=723cc34b7b875111701d9134b443f39b