# SQL and Relational Algebra queries for three tables: student, studies and course

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

I have a following tables, where primary keys are bolded.

student (**SID**, SName, semester)
studies (**SID, CID**)
course (**CID**, CName, CCode)

> Write the SQL queries and Relational Algebra for the following statements.
>
> 1. Find the names of all students in 'third' semester.
> 2. Find the names of all courses studied by 'Ram'.
> 3. Find the total number of students who study 'DBMS'.

Queries that I tried:

SQL:

1. `SELECT SName FROM student WHERE semester='third'`
2. ```
   SELECT CNAME
   FROM student s, studies st, course c
   WHERE s.SID = st.SID AND st.SID = c.CID AND SName = 'Ram'
   ```
3. ```
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM student s, studies st, course c
   WHERE s.SID = st.SID AND st.SID = c.CID AND CName = 'DBMS'
   ```

Relational Algebra:

1. `∏ Sname (σ semester='third' (student))`
2. `∏ Cname (σ Sname='Ram' (student ⋈ studies ⋈ course))`
3. `ρ count(*) (σ Cname='DBMS' (student ⋈ studies ⋈ course))`

Are the queries that I have written correct? If they are wrong, what is the correct solution?

Comment: Comma joins are out of favour these days replace with explicit JOINs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138355/whats-the-difference-between-comma-separated-joins-and-join-on-syntax-in-mysql

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when a process allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your reference. [ask] [help] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Basic questions are faqs, research before considering asking & reflect research.

Comment: Please ask 1 question. Please indent code reasonably. Please read the edit help re block & inline formats for code & quotes, lists, line breaks etc. PS [mre] PS Google 'run relational algebra online'.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you're right

For the second question:

```
SELECT CName
FROM course, studies, student
WHERE course.CID = studies.CID AND
studies.SID = student.SID AND
SName = 'Ram'
```

For the third question:

```
SELECT COUNT(SName)
FROM course, studies, student
WHERE course.CID = studies.CID AND
student.SID = studies.SID AND
CName = 'DBMS'
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered poor. Please explain what was wrong & why this code is correct. [answer] [Help] Please, if you have to "guess" & you're "not sure", you should be posting comments on the question to ask for clarification, not answering. Those don't belong in any answer.