# MySQL: Trouble trying to get my SQL statement to work when condition is true but can also accept false

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.* FROM tableA, tableB WHERE tableA.userUUID = ? AND tableB.uuid=tableA.tableBUUID
```

So when a record in table A has a valid tableBUUID and the tableBUUID exists in tableB then the query runs file. But when I removed the tableBUUID from table B without removing it from the record in tableA then the query returns nothing (Which is obviously expected)

I am wondering how I can change the query so that even if the tableBUUID does not match anything, the query will still return what it can even if its nothing/ blank columns from tableB?

Thanks all

Comment: You need to use a `JOIN`, specifically a `LEFT JOIN`. Your current syntax is akin to using an implicit `INNER JOIN`. Rather than `FROM tableA, tableB`, you'll want `FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON <matching condition>`, where that matching condition is what "matches up" the rows in table A to table B (`tableB.uuid = tableA.tableBUUID`). Side note, SQL statements don't have to be one line, take advantage of newlines for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via a [LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.* 
  FROM tableA 
  LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.uuid = tableA.tableBUUID
WHERE tableA.userUUID = ?
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l1-orcT2).

Performing a `LEFT JOIN` will return data from tableA and matching records from tableB *if it exists in tableB*, otherwise it'll return only the records from tableA.

[image: LEFT JOIN]

In the syntax you posted above in your question, you're essentially doing a `INNER JOIN` by comma separating your tables. This is the old syntax, moving forward you should explicitly write `INNER JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.column_key = b.column_key
```

Read more about it in the following previous question:
[What's the difference between comma separated joins and join on syntax in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138355/whats-the-difference-between-comma-separated-joins-and-join-on-syntax-in-mysql)